# svn diff for non binary files like .jpg, .png

Tags: php, svn

I work with `svn` and i need to find non binary file in between svn sub versions. like i just find out files that is not '.php,.js,.html and .css'
we need to lis out `.jpg, .png, .ttf [font files], .txt` by svn diff

`svn diff -r 223:238`

it it possible to list out non binary files ?